# Realm.io and "Referential Integrity"

Tags: realm

This is an object modeling question.

My model has a "Song" object which is associated with one or more "GenreTag" objects.

GenreTag is not just the type of music ("rock", "pop") but also can be other descriptor types ("80s").

Song objects are associated with GenreTag objects in a one-to-many relationship. I understand that to model this I should have my Song object contain a field that is a list of GenreTag objects.

My question: if I change the definition of a specific GenreTag, how is the change propogated through all the Song objects that have this item in their list of tags? i.e. if I were to change the text in the GenreTag object defining the "rock" tag to "rocked", does this change to that string get propogated to all the Song objects that have "rock" in their list of GenreTag items?

If not, what is the best practice for insuring this type of "referential integrity"?

Comment: I should addo in case it isn't clear that there is a master list of Genre tag objects. A subset of this master list is what gets associated with a particular Song object. In the SQL world I used a many-to-many table that had entries in it to map between a Song and the Genre tables. Essentially standard modeling in the relational world, and used ORM tools to assemble the complete object at runtime.

Comment: But in a true object database I don't see how updates to a GenreTag object propagate to the various Song instances that may be referencing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yep! You're correct. When a Realm object contains a property that is linking to many child Realm objects, that object doesn't exclusively control them.

All the parent Realm object is doing is maintaining a list of pointers to the appropriate `GenreTag` objects; they're not copies, and they're not exclusive to the parent object.

So yes. If you renamed a specific `GenreTag` object, that name change would be instantly apparent if you accessed the same object through a parent `Song` object.